# How to implement new task in Vtiger CRM workflow?

Tags: php, task, workflow, vtiger

I am using vtiger 6 and i would like implement a custom task for my workflow.

let me give more clues.

when you create new workflow in vtiger crm there are 3 step ahead.

1.first, you choose your module and a name for workflow

2.second, you define a condition

3.third (the important one in this issue), you create tasks for your workflow.for example when defined condition is fulfilled then send an sms to a user.

there are some available tasks such as send mail , send sms , create todo and etc.

i would like to implement one of these tasks. because of the poor documentation of vtiger crm i could not understand whats going on behind the scene and i would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Vtiger Provides Option to Invoke Custom Function which you have to define as per your requirement.

You can follow this steps to create a Custom Workflow function.

**STEP1:
create one new file (RegisterWorkflow.php) to register workflow in your vtiger root directory.**

```
require_once 'include/utils/utils.php';
require 'modules/com_vtiger_workflow/VTEntityMethodManager.inc';
$emm = new VTEntityMethodManager($adb);
//$emm->addEntityMethod("Module Name","Label", "Path to file" , "Method Name" );
$emm->addEntityMethod("Leads", "Update Lead", "modules/Leads/UpdateLead.php", "update_lead_data");
```

**STEP2: run that file like.**

> http://YOUR_VTIGER_URL/registerworkflow.php

Note: you must run this file at once. If u run that file more than one time it will create Duplicate entry.

**STEP 3: Go to modules/Leads/UpdateLead.php and Create one Function**

```
function update_lead_data($entity){
    // Your Code here
}
```

> Note : You can include Files which requires to execute you task

**STEP 4: Create Workflow > Select Module for which you defined Custom Function > In step 3 Select Invoke Customer Function > Select Function Name which you Defined > Save**

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain the behind the scenes part(from what I have understood :) ):

1. 1. for cron workflows cron/vtigercron.sh is the star point
      this gets the handler file(cron/modules/com_vtiger_workflow/com_vtiger_workflow.service) for cron from db and executes it.
   2. cron/modules/com_vtiger_workflow/com_vtiger_workflow.service
      It fetches ready tasks from db and calls doTask on them(executes them)
   3. modules/com_vtiger_workflow/VTTaskQueue.inc
      This file fetches ready tasks from db(table com_vtiger_workflowtask_queue)
   4. You will find task types in com_vtiger_workflow_tasktypes table.
      It has handler files for respective tasks which has the doTask method mentioned earlier.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send SMS from CRM then you should do SMS configuration.

- Go to Settings Icon VtigerSettingsIcon.png > Module Manager. This can be found under 'Studio' block.
- Click on Settings Icon SettingsIcon.png next to SMS notifier.
- Click on the link Server Configuration.

Please follow the steps of configuration as described in [SMSNotifier](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/SMSNotifier_Module)

For sending emails from vTiger you have to configure Outgoing server. Once it will be setup then its straight forward to set email workflow.